How can I implement offset hinges on a door too close to a wall?
I have a power chair user in the house and its rough on doors. At 400 lb, hinges give before the chair does. I've installed offset hinges to give us a bit more room in doorways, but there's one where it just won't fit. I can't flip the door. I suppose I could cut away some of the drywall, but would rather not. Any other options to reduce the profile of an opened door?

For reference, below is a regular hinge. When the door is open 90°, it sticks out from the door frame the length of the hinge - about 2.5 inches in my case. We can call this the power chair kill zone. On the right, an offset hinge keeps the door flush with the frame. Its great except when there isn't enough space to mount it.


I'm not clear on how this hing helps you. It'll bend just like the flat hinges did--maybe more since they're longer in the leaves. Surely there's a better approach.

@isherwood - When you open the door 90 degrees with a regular hinge, the door sticks out quite a bit. With an offset hinge, its flush with the frame. I added a picture for clarity.

I understand that. Do you expect it to reduce the frequency of impact, or the severity?

I guess an alternative approach might be to install some tapered slides on the jamb to deflect any potential impact inside the actual opening. Do you need more opening width or is it just a matter of poor aim?

@isherwood - Width is #1 - The door opening is about 29" but that drops 2" because of the hinge. The chair is 25" and it has to turn into the doorway from the hall. Protection is #2 - The chair can catch the door as it turns in, and if the driver keeps hitting the power, it'll pull out the hinge. Your idea of better protection is a good one. I don't mind a few scrapes here and there. Rehanging doors is more of an issue. And its a question of aim! If I'm driving the chair, no scrapes. But if an aide is doing it, it can turn bad quick. The chair occupant can't drive it herself.

Unfortunately you're fighting the laws of space and time here. You won't get those hinges to work, from what I can see, even with mangled drywall. You'd have to create a recess for each hinge or even the entire door. Maybe a half-offset would get you partway there, and then the protection as a secondary measure.

Would a hinge with less offset still provide enough room? Perhaps one a t https://www.amazon.com/s?k=offset+door+hinge might give you an idea. Also, perhaps attaching a curved sheet-metal "bump" across the door might redirect the power chair from hitting the door frame and door edge.

You may want to consider detachable hinges so you could just take the door off when open without needing to undo any hinges. Bit of a manual handling issue though.

Any chance you could simply flip the door—switch from left hand swing to right hand swing?  Also, is this an interior door?
